# Android MediaRecorder - IllegalStateException

Tags: android, mediarecorder

the part of the code that throws exception:

```
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);

        recorder.setOutputFile("test.3gp");
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
```

and i'm getting this exception:

```
E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -38
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.example.amit.recording.RecordService.startRecording(RecordService.java:280)
W/System.err:     at com.example.amit.recording.RecordService.onStartCommand(RecordService.java:141)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3422)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:181)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

the "recorder.start()" is causing this. also when i'm stopping the record, getting this: **"stop called in an invalid state: 0"**
btw - got all the permissions i need in the manifest. thanks!!

**EDIT**

i added "Thread.sleep(2000);" before "prepare()" & "start()", and now it saved a 3gp file in the correct path, but the exceptions are still there - on start() & on stop(). why is it happening?!

Comment: i think you might have problem with file path. use full path ex Envirement.getExternalStorage()+File.seperator+"test.3gp"; also check storage permission.

Comment: The path is ok, and i got storage permission :)

Answer (score 0):

If you targeting greater then 22 then you must have to implement runtime permissions. [See here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for how to implement runtime permission in android.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is the problem

Comment: Please check path of file and also replace default output line. `mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);`

Comment: not working, thanks for trying. i edited the question, please read it

Comment: this problem causing by this Audio source
   `recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);`
not working on your device and android! change that to

   `recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);`

Comment: MIC throws the same exception. Also maybe i should added, the error i get when i stop the record: "stop called in an invalid state: 0"